# Simple BounceIn Image Flutter Animation

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, animation

**What i want?**

I want to do simple animation with this image.

**What does it mean?**

If i click on it, it should make smooth for example bounce in animation. Im open in ways through which we can achieve this effect.

**What i tried?**

I thought AnimatedContainer will get done but `curve:` parameter is not doing anything.

*ps. *I am beginner**

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Poppy App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

double _imgwidth = 200;
double _imgheight = 200;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void poopAnimationIn() async {
    setState(() {
      _imgheight = 300;
      _imgwidth = 300;
    });
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        _imgheight = 200;
        _imgwidth = 200;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(164, 117, 81, 1),
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            poopAnimationIn();
          },
          child: AnimatedContainer(
              curve: Curves.bounceIn,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              child: Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                width: _imgwidth,
                height: _imgheight,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size for AnimatedContainer and change that size in setState.

Here is the edited code:
I suggest you use other curves like easeIn instead of bounceIn to have a smoother animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Poppy App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  double initialHeight = 200;
  double initialImageHeight = initialHeight;
  double expandedImageHeight = 300;
  void poopAnimationIn() async {
    setState(() {
      initialImageHeight = expandedImageHeight;
    });
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        initialImageHeight = initialHeight;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(164, 117, 81, 1),
        child: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                poopAnimationIn();
              },
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                  height: initialImageHeight,
                  curve: Curves.bounceIn,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),

                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
//                 width: _imgwidth,
//                 height: _imgheight,
                  ))),
        ),
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```